# How do I get a Golden Heart, and what advantages do they have?

Tags: pixel-people

I have played Pixel People for a couple of days now and I am confused on the golden hearts. Sometimes, after the heart fills up, a golden heart appears in the heart counter at the top of the screen. I don't know how I did this, so can anyone clarify how to conduct this procedure? Also, what advantages to the golden hearts bring? A special reward? Nothing at all?

I would also love sources. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have my information from [Wikia](http://pixelpeople.wikia.com/wiki/Heart#Golden_Hearts). You can get these golden hearts when the couple in the house produces offspring. It depends on which line it is when there are multiple couples in a house (the 4+ buildings). More golden hearts when you complete the heart counter is believed to give a better reward, but that is not sure.

I do not know how you can determine if a couple can produce offspring. Some couples that produce offspring are the following:

- Mechanic-Engineer
- Sheriff-Sheriff
- Lawyer-Sheriff
- Marine-Soldier
- Writer-Artist
- Athlete-Athlete
- Cameraman-Cameraman
- Writer-Writer
- Ballet Dancer-Rapper
- Athlete-Cheerleader
- Plumber-Construction Worker
- Bartender-Waiter
- Programmer-Programmer
- Programmer-Artist
- Assistant-Civil Servant
- Guitarist-Bassist
- Caddie-Cheerleader
- Figure Skater-Mountain Climber
- Sommelier-Chef
- Gym Instructor-Martial Artist
- Gymnast-Ringmaster
- Talkshow Host-Reporter
- Skateboarder-Olympic Swimmer
- Wrestler-Figure Skater
- Scientist-Mathematician
- Scientist-Doctor
- Gardener-Farmer