# Can you move people in Pixel People?

Tags: pixel-people

From [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173098/how-do-i-get-a-golden-heart-and-what-advantages-do-they-have) question we see that it can be important to have a specific couple in a house. In order to get more 'good' couples I would like to move people between or insidfe houses, is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it costs Utopium.  You will need a Hotel to do this.

1. Go to the house where you want to move a person.
2. Tap the person to be moved.
3. Tap the golden button on the top left corner.
4. Choose "Hotel" in the resulting menu.
5. Do this with as many people as you need to move, up to 6.
6. Go to a house that you want to move a person in to.
7. Tap the empty person slot that you want to move the person in to.
8. Go to the Hotel, tap the person you want to move in.
9. Choose which job to send them back to.
10. If is more than one person you want to move, go back to 6.

This will cost 1u for each person you need to move.  Make sure that you don't send the person to the Mothership when moving them to the hotel, as this will destroy that person, which still costs you 1u.